# Possible mistake in calculating this probability

Tags: probability

Say I have 4 people in the room A, B, C, and D. And I want to calculate the probability that at least 2 people have their first name starting with same letter. 
I tried these two ways:

i) First calculating the probability that none of the people have their first name starting with the same letter and then subtracting it by 1.

I got: 
P(no two people have their first name starting with the same letter) = (26/26)*(25/26)*(24/26)*(23/26) = 0.7851615839. 
So the desired probability is 0.2148384161

ii) Second, calculating individual probabilities:

P(2 people with same first letter) = (4C2) * (26/26)*(1/26)*(25/26)*(24/26) =0.204824761
P(3 people with same first letter) = (4C3) * (26/26) *(1/26)*(1/26)*(25/26) =0.0056895767
P(4 people with same first letter) = (4C4) * (26/26^4) = 0.0000568957

So adding up I get P(desired) = 0.2105712335

What did I do wrong here? Why are the two answers different?

Comment: In $(ii)$, you are missing a case

Comment: I thought the same. Sadly, I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Comment: To elaborate., in (*ii*) you forgot about the possibility that you have two people whose name starts with $A$ and a different two people whose name starts with $B$, i.e. two separate letters each of which occur twice.

Comment: @JMoravitz got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: As an aside, you would notice that when you used `*`'s to try to denote multiplication, you caused some of your text to be placed in italics.  Enclosing a block of text within a single set of stars `*like this*` makes it italicised *like this*.  Similarly, enclosing within double stars `**like this**` makes it bold **like this**.  To use math symbols, enclose within dollar signs and use the name of the symbol after a slash: `$\frac{26}{26}\times\frac{25}{26}\times\cdots$` produces $\frac{26}{26}\times\frac{25}{26}\times\cdots$

Comment: For more information on how to properly type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site, [visit this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).